# residue of $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}$ at $\infty$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'm trying to find the residue of $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}$ at $\infty$, while computing $\int^1_0  \sqrt[3]{x^2(1-x)} dx$

I know that I can compute it using $g(w) = -w^{-2} f(1/w)$ at $w = 0$ ([Residue at infinity, contradiction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661877/residue-at-infinity-contradiction)).

So I have  $g(w)=\frac{-1}{w^2} \sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{w^2} (1-\frac{1}{w})}=\frac{-1}{w^2} \sqrt[3]{\frac {1}{w^3} (w-1)}$.

And here I don't know what to do. I want to put $\frac{1}{w^3}$ out of the root, can one do this? And why? And if not what one can do? Could you please help me to find the residue explicitly?

Comment: There are three analytic branches of $f$ on $\mathbb C \setminus [0, 1]$. They can be written as
$$e^{(2 k + 1) \pi i/3} z (1 - z^{-1})^{1/3},$$
where $z^{1/3}$ is the principal branch. Take one of those branches to be $f$ and find the coefficient $c_{-1}$ at $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series of $f$ on $|z| > 1$ from the binomial theorem. Then
$$\int_0^1 (f(z + i0) - f(z - i0)) \, dz =
2 \pi i \operatorname* {Res}_{z = \infty} f(z) = 
-2 \pi i c_{-1}.$$

Comment: @Maxim could you please write how one can find the residue explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that you can just pull $w^3$ out of the cube root because the ambiguity in $w$ is a phase factor of $e^{2\pi in}$ for some integer $n$, and when you cube it and take the cube root you still have $e^{2\pi in}=1$. The problem is that that's the easy part. The hard part is determining the phase of the cube root. Let's look at the original contour, as I assume is in your solution:
[image: fig 1]

The little red circles mark out the branch points at $0$ and $1$. Here as the radii of the circles decrease towards $0$ the integral from $A$ to $B$ becomes the one you are trying to evaluate but as we travel clockwise from $B$ through $C$ and then to $D$ the phase of the cube root decreases by $e^{-2\pi i/3}$ so the integral around the contour, given that the integrals around the circles will shrink to $0$ as their radii do, will be
$$\oint_Cf(z)dz=\left(1-e^{-2\pi 1/3}\right)\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}\,dz=2ie^{-\pi i/3}\sin(\pi/3)I=i\sqrt3e^{-\pi i/3}I$$
After the transformation $w=1/z$ the picture in the $w$-plane is as shown below:
[image: fig 2]
At $B^{\prime}$ we hope the the phase of $w$ matches that of $z$ at $B$, hence both $0$ and the phase of the cube root should match as well. Since the phase at $C$ is $e^{-\pi i/3}$ then we have
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{w-1}{w^3}}=\frac1w\sqrt[3]{(1-w)}e^{-\pi i/3}$$
So we see that the effective integrand will be
$$-\frac1{w^3}\sqrt[2]{1-w}e^{-\pi i/3}$$
And the residue at $0$ (marked with a black X) will be
$$\lim_{w\rightarrow0}\frac1{2!}\frac{d^2}{dw^2}\left(w^3\left(-\frac1{w^3}\sqrt[3]{(1-w}e^{-\pi i/3}\right)\right)=-\frac12\left(-\frac29\right)e^{-\pi i/3}=\frac19e^{-\pi i/3}$$
Since we circled the pole at zero counterclockwise in Figure 2, we have
$$i\sqrt3e^{-\pi i/3}I=2\pi i\left(\frac19e^{-\pi i/3}\right)$$
So our answer is that
$$I=\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}dz=\frac{2\pi}{9\sqrt3}$$
As could have been determined more easily by recognizing the integral as a Beta function. Another thing you might have done is to consider that the answer has to be positive real so you could have ignored the phase of the cube root in the residue calculation and just taken the absolute value of whatever result you got, but that wouldn't have answered your question :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the residue at $z=\infty$ for this function $f(z)=\sqrt[3]{z^2(1-z)}$. This is because $f(z)$ is not analytic for $|z|>R$ for any large $R>0$.

Comment: It's true that $(z^2 (1 - z))^{1/3}$ is not analytic on $|z| > R$, but you can choose a branch of $f$ which is, since $\infty$ is not a branch point of $f$.